# How do you minimize t instead of an objective function over t?

Tags: optimization, boundary-value-problem

Let $\mathbf{x}(t) : \mathbb{R}\rightarrow\mathbb{R}^{n}$ be a vector-valued function, and $\{\mathbf{x}_{0}, \mathbf{x}_{t}, \mathbf{v}_{0}, \mathbf{v}_{t}, c\}$ constants. With $\mathbf{x}(0) = \mathbf{x}_{0}$, $\mathbf{x}(T) = \mathbf{x}_{t}$, $\mathbf{x}'(0) = \mathbf{v}_{0}$, $\mathbf{x}'(T) = \mathbf{v}_{t}$, $|\mathbf{x}''(t)| = c$, find $\mathbf{x}(t)$ that minimizes $T$.

I’ve been looking into variational calculus and optimal control theory, but all the methods I’ve seen are for optimizing an objective function over a *fixed* interval, as opposed to optimizing *the interval itself*.

Comment: How do we know there is any solution $\mathbf x(t)$ at all that satisfied the various conditions?

Comment: It's relatively straightforward to see that a solution exists for any c > 0. You could always construct x to accelerate arbitrarily far away, then cancel any velocity, then do a bang-bang approach to a point x1 (also at 0 velocity) such that you can go from x1 to xt at direct acceleration and satisfy the final constraints. Clearly not optimal, but clearly exists.